# Question about reinforcement learning's training data

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to create a simple reinforcement learning model to play the 2048 game.

According to the "[Playing Atari with deep reinforcement learning](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv8f3fx7PMAhUJipQKHQHeCxIQFgggMAA&url=%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%77%77%77%2E%63%73%2E%74%6F%72%6F%6E%74%6F%2E%65%64%75%2F%7E%76%6D%6E%69%68%2F%64%6F%63%73%2F%64%71%6E%2E%70%64%66&usg=AFQjCNEd1AJoM72DeDpI_GBoPuv7NnVoFA)" the loss function I use is

```
Loss = R[n] + ratio * max(inc_score|a + Q(S[n+1]|a)) - Q(S[n])

R[n] -> current score<br>
S[n+1] -> The board of next movement<br>
Q(S[n]) -> Current board's Q score with a 3 layers NN<br>
inc_score -> The score could get after a specific action
```

I randomly generated training data in the form of:
 
R[n], S[n], S[n+1]|a Inc|a 
(Include 4 possible actions, left, right, up, down, I randomly pick one in each step)
And update the parameters with a standard SGD.

But the NN looks never getting converge.

My Question is
Q1: Is my understanding correct for this case and RL?
Q2: Is that OK to use randomly generated training data, or I have to generate the training the data according to the current Q value.